# Writing a SQL query with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have this so far:

```
var query = (from g in this.Context.Groups
    where g.ID == groupID &&
          g.TaxId == groupTaxId
    select g.Group_K);
```

Then the `SQL` query I want to add is this:

```
select zipCode 
from ADDRESSES 
where ADDRESS_K in 
   (select ADDRESS_K 
    from GROUPADDRESS 
    where GROUP_K = "is in Group_K found above "
       and address_type = "address type variable I pass into this method"
       and ACTIVE = 1)
```

Notice that `GROUPADDRESS` is the bridge table between `GROUPS` and `Addresses` table that has `Group_K` and `Address_K` 
I can't figure it out how to add a new `LINQ` query or update the one I have to account for the new `SQL` I am trying to add.  Thanks for help.

```
Groups Table:  Group_K, ID, TaxId
Addresses Table: Address_K, Zip
GroupAddress Table:  Group_K, Address_K, Address_Type
```

Comment: Can your SQL not be done with an inner join?

Comment: Can you share the table structure and your original SQL please?

Comment: @kidshaw well yeah, how ever it does the job is fine.

Comment: @shree.pat18 Original SQL is there in the question! The first one I directly wrote LINQ for it so I don't have a orignal SQL for it and it is prety simple to understand! I added Table structure!

Comment: Not criticising - but a join makes the LINQ equivalent much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a GroupAddress in your context:

```
var query = (from g in this.Context.Groups
join ga in this.Context.GroupAddress on g.AddressK equals ga.AddressK
where g.ID == groupID &&
      g.TaxId == groupTaxId
select g.Group_K);
```

Edit:

Right so GroupAddress sits between Group and Address. Assuming you've set up relationships in your database, you will have navigation properties you can test against:

```
where g.Address == ''
```

EF drops link tables so your navigation is simpler. If not available in EF, add another join to the above.

```
var query = (from g in this.Context.Groups
join ga in this.Context.GroupAddress on g.Group_K equals ga.Group_K
join a in this.Context.GroupAddress on g.Address_K equals ga.Address_K
where g.ID == groupID &&
      g.TaxId == groupTaxId
select g.Group_K);
```

Comment: g is groups I posted structure in the question for. So g does not have a Address_K as in "on g.AddressK" on your secnd line of code

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
var groupID=1;
var groupTaxId=1;
var result=
(
    from a in this.Context.ADDRESSES
    where
    (
        from ga in this.Context.GROUPADDRESS
        join g in this.Context.Groups
            on g.GROUP_K equals ga.GROUP_K
        where ga.ID == groupID
        where g.TaxId== groupTaxId
        where ga.ACTIVE == 1
        select ga.ADDRESS_K
    ).Contains(a.ADDRESS_K)
    select new
    {
        a.zipCode
    }
).ToList();
```

Comment: @ConfusedSleepyDeveloper : Okay. What is not right with that?

Comment: ID is a column in Groups table, Group_K is the Key for groups table. Two different columns.

Comment: @ConfusedSleepyDeveloper : So you mean like this?